# Program to compute Histogram of the image

Tags: java, opencv, histogram

I have program in Java using OpenCV that is designed to calculate the histogram of the image. 
Class to calculate histogram is

```
public class Histogram1D {

   private final int numberOfBins = 256;
   private float minRange = 0.0f;
   private float maxRange = 255.0f;

   public CvHistogram getHistogram(IplImage image, IplImage mask) {
      int dim = 1;
      int[] sizes = new int[numberOfBins];
      int histType = CV_HIST_ARRAY;
      float[][] ranges = new float[(int) minRange][(int) maxRange];
      CvHistogram hist = cvCreateHist(dim, sizes, histType, ranges, 1);
      int accumulate = 0;
      cvCalcHist(new IplImageArray(image), hist, accumulate, mask);
      return hist;
   }

   public float[] getHistogramAsArray(IplImage image) {
      CvHistogram histogram = getHistogram(image, null);
      float[] dest = new float[numberOfBins];
      for (int bin = 0; bin < numberOfBins; bin++) {
         dest[bin] = cvQueryHistValue_1D(histogram, bin);
      }
      cvReleaseHist(histogram);
      return dest;
   }
}
```

and Main class is

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      Histogram1D h = new Histogram1D();
      IplImage image =  cvLoadImage("data/group.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
      float[] histogram = h.getHistogramAsArray(image);     
      int numberOfPixels = image.width() + image.height();
      System.out.println("Number of pixels  : " + numberOfPixels);        
   }
}
```

My problem is that when I put this line of code: float[] histogram = h.getHistogramAsArray(image); to Main class and run project I get this error message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff9b0613f0e, pid=2744, tid=1072

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [opencv_imgproc248.dll+0xc3f0e]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\...........\hs_err_pid2744.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Can anyone help me, what does this message mean and where I have problem in code please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with your *opencv_imgproc248.dll* library on the native part, not in your code.

Comment: Do you have any solution to solve this problem, because I have no idea how to repair it ?

Comment: Give us a look to error report file (C:\...........\hs_err_pid2744.log) (as an edit to your question)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved this problem with change variables to these   int[] sizes = new int[]{numberOfBins};
        int histType = CV_HIST_ARRAY;
        float[] minMax = new float[]{minRange, maxRange};
        float[][] ranges = new float[]{minMax};                                                                                                     and it helps me